# Get a variable from PHP into a Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I've researched the similar questions but am unable to get anything to work (I'm very new to PHP and JQuery).

I so far have this function set up, which pulls the values for id and tip like I want them to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip').click(function(){
        var id      = $(this).attr('tooltip-id');
        var tip     = $(this).attr('data-tooltip');
        var target  = $('div#tooltip-modal');
        $.fancybox(target);

    });
```

Here is the relevant div:

```
<div id="tooltip-modal" style="display:none">
    <h2>Edit the description of this item:</h2>
    <form id="update-tooltip">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="id">
        Tooltip body: <textarea name="body" class="input">{{tip}}</textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="update">
    </form>
</div>
```

I want the values for tip and id to show up in their respective destinations (id is hidden, tip should be the body of a textarea that will hopefully be editable by the user).  I feel like this should be simple, no?  I've tried every method of passing it in; I see people have recommended AJAX, but I'm new to that too and fairly certain I did it wrong (if that's even the right way to go).

I eventually will need to save the modified tip text to a database, but that's a problem for another day.  If that influences your solution, though, now you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
    var id      = $(this).attr('tooltip-id');
    var tip     = $(this).attr('data-tooltip');
```

To something like (can be shortened if necessary):

```
    var id      = $(this).attr('tooltip-id');
    var tip     = $(this).attr('data-tooltip');

    $("#id").val(id);
    // a bit longer as the textarea does not have an ID
    $("#tooltip-modal .input").val(tip);
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD.  Why in the world was that such a hard solution to find?  I knew it would be something simple.  Thank you very much!